# How does $d=ab-({1\over2}h)^2$ imply: $|d|=({1\over2}h)^2+|ab|$. Hence $|{1\over2}h|<\sqrt{|d|}$, and $|ab|=|d|-({1\over2}h)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose $a,h,b$ are integers where $ab <0$. Suppose we have $d=ab-({1\over2}h)^2$. Considering this, I am having trouble understanding the following implications:

$|d|=({1\over2}h)^2+|ab|$. Hence, $|{1\over2}h|<\sqrt{|d|}$, and $|ab|=|d|-({1\over2}h)^2$

**How does $d=ab-({1\over2}h)^2$ imply those equations?**

> This is coming from Conway's *The Sensual (quadratic) Form*; page 21.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since $ab<0$ clearly $d<0$ that means the all terms in the equality are negative. Than we can take absolute value of them $|d|=|ab|+|-1/2h)^2|=|ab|+|1/2h^2|$. Other properties follow immediately.

Comment: Beat me to it! +1

Comment: Are we allowed to take the absolute value of each term individually? I thought we would need to take absolute value of both sides and so how would we get $|d|= ({1\over2}h)^2+|ab|$?

Comment: Yes you can if they are of the same sign

Comment: Doesn't that contradict the triangle inequality?

Comment: You have the equality with all elements of common negative sign. Inverting sign you get $x=y+z$ where $x,y,z$ are positive. Triangle inequality is not relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $d$ is obviously negative, so $|d|=-d$. Same remark applies to $ab$, so we have

$$|d|=-d=(\frac{1}{2}h)^2-ab=(\frac{1}{2}h)^2+|ab|$$. Substracting $(\frac{1}{2}h)^2$, we obtained

$$|d|-(\frac{1}{2}h)^2=|ab|$$

Now, if $x>0$, $y>0$, then $x+y<x$, so $\sqrt{x+y}<\sqrt{x}$. Use this with $|d|=(\frac{1}{2}h)^2+|ab|$ and $x=(\frac{1}{2})^2$ and $y=|ab|$ to get the required inequality.

Comment: How did he get: Hence, $|{1\over2}h|<\sqrt{|d|}$, and $|ab|=|d|-({1\over2}h)^2$?

Comment: I edited my answer.